# Is the video of the Russian talent show archery tragedy faked?

Tags: mortality, video

This video has been around for a few years, but the first time I saw this I was shocked and disturbed.

[Got talent goes horribly wrong archer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fFDEalKXT8&has_verified=1) <sup>[not safe for work]</sup>

I have looked online and have found competing information being claimed that the video was a marketing campaign, and other videos claiming this is not true and that it is in fact real.

[Snopes further claims that this is Undetermined](http://www.snopes.com/photos/accident/russiantalent.asp)

Can anybody verify if the video is real and if so, can it be confirmed if the man indeed died?  It certainly appears like he did.

Comment: btw. "NSFW AND GRAPHIC"? srsly, there isn't even a drop of blood in there..

Comment: This is currently going viral on Facebook. (I think through some FB social engineering, but I am not inclined to check.)

Comment: Perhaps a short description of the contents of the video is in order?

Comment: Snopes is now showing it as "False".

Comment: YouTube removed the video, so the link is no longer valid. Does anyone have an updated link?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's obviously not real. At very first glance it looks like a parody. But since you want some "hard evidence", here it goes.

- Whole setup is very, very amateur, too amateur to be considered from a show on national TV in Russia (or Ukraine for that matter)
- TV station logo is: `TVД`, yet in [Cyrillic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets) there is no `V`, obviously no `TVД` station exist
- It's allegedly Russian show, yet show logo says "Talent" in Latin alphabet
- Actual Russian "Got Talent" franchise is called [Минута славы](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuta_slavy)
- Caption's second line says "Киева", which would point to Ukraine, rather than Russia
- But than again, [Ukraine Got Talent (Україна має талант)](http://talant.stb.ua/) has completely different logo, is show on a different TV station and fully professional setup
- Caption says "Удивительный братьями ", which is supposed to mean  "Amazing brothers", however it's grammatically incorrect (singular adjective instead of plural, and noun in wrong [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_grammar#Nouns) - instrumental instead of nominative). Same goes for second line, it's also ungrammatical, should either read "з Киева" or just "Киев"
- No one in the whole video speaks a single word, further showing that whoever made that video had no knowledge of Russian nor Ukrainian
- The arrow nocking changes color midflight
- The "victim" falls politely to the ground like he's about to make a snow angel - there's no pain on display, frantic flailing, etc

Comment: `whole setup is very, very amateur, too amateur to be considered from a show on national TV in Russia (or Ukraine for that matter).`  I have heard the argument that this was auditions to get on the show, the lack of professional stage setup can be explained by this.  I do admit though that if I was a camera man and I witnessed someone take an arrow to the head, my first reaction would not be to cue to the judges to capture their reaction.

Comment: @maple_shaft: looks to lame even for an audition. Also in real audition they would say who they are, and what they are gonna perform.

Comment: Mixing English and Russian/Ukranian sounds half-way plausible to me, but I did a search for "TVД" and the main hits were for this video, and no hits for it exist within wikipedia.org.

Comment: Why is the use of the Latin alphabet in branding surprising though?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Because a) "talent show" is kind of generic name, not a brand, b) branded talent show formats, like eg. Got Talent or Idol have their local variants with their names translated to local language.

Comment: @vartec: not always true. In Italy the show is called *Italia's got talent*. On the other hand the French have *La France a un incroyable talent*. Guess it goes down to marketing (having an English title is quite cool in Italy, it would be considered almost preposterous in France)

Comment: [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/photos/accident/russiantalent.asp) concur, and suggest it is a promotion for cola.

Comment: Another argument would be the lack of blood. As far as my archery experience goes, an arrow can easily penetrate a human skull, yet there is no drop of blood anywhere. Besides, the background music sound more like chesp pornography than a nationalwide TV show.

Comment: @DavidStockinger, how many human skulls you penetrated?

Comment: Most of your arguments are extremely subjective. Apart from clearly broken grammar, everything else is just a speculation. I.e., TVД is absolutely a plausible channel name, borrowed English word can be mixed up with Russian, nothing wrong with that. I mean, it's obviously a comedy sketch, but "obviously" is hardly a proof.

Comment: @sashkello, _TVД_ is really untypical channel name for Russia/Ukraine (though theoretically possible). On the other hand, (in this resolution) I don't see _TVД_ there, I see a stylized _TVA_ (which is [a really existing Ukrainian channel](https://tva.ua/onair/) but still seems to have another logo and not to be a broadcaster of Ukraine's Got Talent or similar shows). A comment [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=St6ysh0EIrA&lc=UgzB2s23mfFgyvidG6B4AaABAg) describes some goofs in the video itself.